# Windows Phone 7 Button Left-Top from Code

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can i use android style gravity, and gavityTop=20px, Left=30px in Windows Phone 7?

```
        Button btn = new Button() { 
            Content="newbutton "+i, 
            Margin=new Thickness(20)
        };
```

id like something to control my button's left/top margin from the top/left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want something like this:

```
HorizontalAlignment = HoriztontalAlignment.Left,
VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
Margin = new Thickness(30,20,0,0),//left 30, top 20, right 0, bottom 0
```

P.S.: untested, maybe including typos. don't have a SDK on this PC